# Unable to connect to database

Tags: winforms, sql-server-2012, connection-string, clickonce

d I am now able to connect to database. But my solution file is not executable in other systems even though they have the same database in their local machines.

Below are the steps followed

1. Wrote a connection string to connect to local server (Which worked for my system)
2. Using ClickOnce deployment wizard I have published an executable file for other systems which have same DB in their local systems
3. I ran the executable file and was unable to connect to database
4. I copied the source code to other System and executed it with Visual Studio 2015 . I was still unable to connect to local database

I am attaching the source code , queries used to generate tables in db. Kindly help me resolve this issue.
Your support will be of great help in finishing the project.

Source Code: 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByMwP0UkvEAFWDdsbDZEVExXb3c/view?usp=sharing

Text file for sql queries to create tables

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByMwP0UkvEAFLWU3MG13VTdpNzQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Have you installed SQL Server on you computer? Which SQL version have you installed?

Comment: Yes.. Its 2012 express edition..

Answer (score 0):

In App.config file
If SQL Instance is SQLEXPRESS, you must repalce `Data Source=.` to `Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS`. I hope it help you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Login_Page.Properties.Settings.PharmaDBConnectionString"
        connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\PharmaDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="PharmDB"
        connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=PharmaDB;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I did not work.. Is possible to transfer all the forms to another project? I think i messed up the project